# Access 2007 Use VBA

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2007

I have data in access in the form of a table. I need to export it to excel in the form of an excel sheet where i should even be able to make updates to the data if necessary. I have to do this using VBA. And also one more thing the data I have in access is which i have generated using SQL

Comment: Why do you think it needs to be in Excel?

Answer (score 0):

Why do this with VBA? There are multiple simple ways to do this from the normal interface options.

And what do you mean by, "the data I have in access is which i have generated using SQL"?

Answer (score 0):

[Modules: Sample Excel Automation](http://www.mvps.org/access/modules/mdl0006.htm) - cell by cell which is slow

[Modules: Transferring Records to Excel with Automation](http://www.mvps.org/access/modules/mdl0035.htm)